# Is it possible to add individual labels to Chart.JS bars?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, chart.js

I have a fully functional Chart.JS Barchart which loads as intended, however I would like to add the username to each bar which is associated to them so administrators (who can see all entries) can distinguish between them.

```
function BarChart(data) {
                var barChartData = {
                    labels: data.Month,
                    datasets: [
                        {
                            label: 'Weight (kg)',
                            fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
                            backgroundColor: "rgba(46, 44, 211, 0.7)",
                            highlightFill: "rgba(220,220,220,0.75)",
                            highlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                            data: data.Weight
                        },
                        {
                            label: 'Steps',
                            fillColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)",
                            backgroundColor: "rgba(215, 44, 44, 0.7)",
                            highlightFill: "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)",
                            highlightStroke: "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)",
                            data: data.Steps
                        }
                    ]

                }
                var ctx = document.getElementById("barchart").getContext("2d");
                window.myBar =new Chart(ctx, {
                    type: 'bar',
                    data: barChartData,
                    options: { responsive: true }
                });
```

I have successfully passed through the Usernames and they can be called by using data.User, however when I append this to the Steps or Weight label, I end up with "Steps for: admin,admin,admin" (since I have three entries, all from admin).

Is it possible to have it so each bar has the username it belongs to?

Comment: Use highcharts if you can, the can do everything.

Comment: I'd prefer to use an open-source solution, would you recommend anything else? The issue with choosing another option at this point is that I've just managed to get the chart working nicely (except for the username part).

Comment: Chart.js is working good enough, but they have limited possibilities. I don't remember if they have this feature for naming, what I remember it can't not be compared with highcharts. If the data is not secure so the api could be online you can check the google charts too, they are free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe not quite what you asked for, but you could add it to the tooltip.

```
options: {
  tooltips:{
    callbacks: {
       afterLabel: function(e){return "added By:" +data.User[e.datasetIndex][e.index]}
    }
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/r71no58a/7/

Comment: So I managed to get it working using some of the logic you provided:
options: {
                            responsive: true,
                            tooltips: {
                                callbacks: {
                                    afterLabel: function (e) { return "Owner: " + data.User[e.index] }
                                }
                            }
                        }

Thanks!